# 'Session state is not available in this context.' from HttpApplication().Session call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to build a multi-step registration form and have a session to contain data throughout the process. When my application first loads it attempts set a session variable for use. However, I get the following error message when my application first loads:

Exception details:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Session state is not available in this context.
```

Source Error:

```
HttpSessionState session = new HttpApplication().Session;
```

My controller action is as follows:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Registration
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpSessionState session = new HttpApplication().Session;

        CustomerStatusModel model = new CustomerStatusModel();
        model.CustomerStatusId = session["CustomerStatusId"];

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I'm new to MVC 5 and also new to posting on StackOverflow. I could not find any similar posts. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to call `Session` and you're not working on an action, eg. an attribute, you can access with

```
HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't access `Session` by creating a new `HttpApplication`.

Just access `Session` directly, as it's a property of the `Controller` class.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //DON'T DO THIS
    //HttpSessionState session = new HttpApplication().Session;

    CustomerStatusModel model = new CustomerStatusModel();

    //USE this.Session INSTEAD
    model.CustomerStatusId = Session["CustomerStatusId"]; 

    return View(model);
}
```